# Error with Sign Up PHP page

Tags: php, html

EDIT

---

SO I figured out a fix. I replaced the while statement with an if and it worked perfectly. Thanks to everyone who helped out!

---

I was making a sign up page when this error came up ( I'm still kind of new to programming and php so this might explain what the error is and I just don't know)

> Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /Users/Jacob/Sites/website/postregister.php on line 22

Here's my code:

```
<!-- start sign up form -->
            <?php
            include("config.php");
            $firstname = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['firstname']);
            $lastname = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['lastname']);
            $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['email']);
            $birthyear = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['birthyear']);
            $city = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['city']);
            $address = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['address']);
            $state = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['state']);
            $phone = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['phone']);
            $password = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['password']);
            $zipcode= mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['zipcode']);
            $active = 0;
            $hash = md5( rand(0,1000) ); // Generate random 32 character hash and assign it to a local variable.
            $sql= mysql_query("INSERT INTO member (firstname, lastname, email, phone, city, state, address, zipcode, password, hash, active)
            VALUES

            ('$firstname','$lastname','$email','$phone', '$city', '$state','$address', '$zipcode', '$password', '$hash', '$active')")or die(mysql_error());
                                    while($row == mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
                                    $to = $email; //Send email to our user
                                    $subject = 'Signup | Verification'; //// Give the email a subject 
                                    $message = '

                                    Thanks for signing up!<br/>
                                    Your account has been created, you can login with the following credentials after you have activated your account by pressing the url below.<br/>

                                    ------------------------------------------------------------------------------<br/>
                                    Email: '.$email.'<br/>
                                    Password: '.$password.'<br/>
                                    ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

                                    <a href="http://localhost/~jacob/pages/verify.php?email='.$email.'&hash='.$hash.'">Please Click Here to Activate Your Account</a>

                                    '; // Our message above including the link

                                    $headers  = "From: customersupport@example.com\r\n"; 
                                    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
                                    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers); // Send the email
                                }

            ?>
            <form action="postregister.php" method="post">
                <label for="firstname">First Name:</label><br/>
                <input type="text" name="firstname" value="" size='90' style='height:20px;' /><br/><br/>
                <label for="lastname">Last Name:</label><br/>
                <input type="text" name="lastname" value="" size='90' style='height:20px;'/><br/><br/>
                <label for="email">Email:</label><br/>
                <input type="text" name="email" value="" size='90' style='height:20px;'/><br/><br/>
                <label for="birthyear">Birthyear:</label><br/>
                <input type="text" name="birthyear" value="" size='90' style='height:20px;'/><br/><br/>
                <label for="city">City:</label><br/>
                <input type="text" name="city" value="" size='90' style='height:20px;'/><br/><br/>
                <label for="phone">Phone:</label><br/>
                <input type="text" name="phone" value="" size='90' style='height:20px;'/><br/><br/>
                <label for="address">Address:</label><br/>
                <input type="text" name="address" value="" size='90' style='height:20px;'/><br/><br/>
                <label for="zipcode">Zipcode:</label><br/>
                <input type="text" name="zipcode" value="" size='90' style='height:20px;'/><br/><br/>
                <label for="State">State:</label><br/>
                <input type="text" name="state" value="" size='90' style='height:20px;'/><br/><br/>
                <label for="password">Password:</label><br/>
                <input type="password" name="password" value="" size='90' style='height:20px;'/><br/><br/>


                <input type="submit" class="submit_button" value="Sign up" />
            </form>
```

Any help would be **GREATLY** appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: This is actually the most popular question on SO.  See: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Warning%3A+mysql_fetch_array%28%29+expects+parameter+1+to+be+resource%2C+boolean+given

Comment: Also, as a side-critique- might be time to switch to PDO or Mysqli.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your query is returning **false**.  I would imagine there's an error with your database connection.  Try printing your query and running it manually on your database to confirm it's running properly.  You can also just try a simple:

```
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM member LIMIT 10");
 $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
 print_r($row);
```

And see what happens.  I imagine this will error out too.  Check your `include("config.php");` and be sure your DB link is set up and working properly.  To confirm your $sql isn't getting a valid result you can try dumping it out and seeing what type it is using either print_r or var_dump.  Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

Please read the manual for [`mysql_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php). Under *Return Values*...

> For other type of SQL statements, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, DROP, etc, mysql_query() returns TRUE on success or FALSE on error.

As your query is an `INSERT` type statement, `mysql_query()` will return a boolean. There are also no rows to fetch.

You can probably change your code to the following

```
$result = mysql_query("All that SQL");
if ($result === false) {
    // or die() is a terrible way to handle errors
    throw new Exception(mysql_error());
}

$to = $email;
// and so on
```

Answer (score 1):

Most people seeing this message have simply forgotten to check for an error in executing their statement. You've already got that covered with the `or die` portion of the `mysql_query` line.

*Your* problem is that you're trying to loop through the resulting rows from an `INSERT`, but an `INSERT` doesn't return a set of rows. From the PHP docs:

> For other type of SQL statements, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, DROP, etc,
>   mysql_query() returns TRUE on success or FALSE on error.

You're not actually using `$row` inside your loop anyway.

Instead of the loop and `mysql_fetch_array`, you could just check to see if `mysql_query` returned true, in which case your row was added and you can send your email. The way you've already written the query, though I wouldn't personally recommend it, actually makes this very easy: you just have to send the email right after the query line, because you're already `die`ing in case of an error.

Comment: +1, glad somebody else saw the obvious here though I wouldn't recommend using `or die()` as a way to handle errors